# Why does vim complain "no version information available" for libtinfo?

Tags: vim

Every time I run `vim`, it opens successfully but outputs the error message `vim: /usr/lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by vim)`.

I already have `libtinfo` installed:

```
➜  repo ls -l /usr/lib/libtinfo.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16  2月 13  2020 /usr/lib/libtinfo.so.6 -> libncursesw.so.6
```

but the message still pops out every time.

My question is:

How do I fix it?

Why is the message shown?